# Anchor breaks tilde

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use tilde for changing opacity of another element, but I also need the element to have an anchor tag but this breaks the transition. To clearify I have 2 elements. `#china`, and `#map`. When I hover `#china` I want `#map` to change opacity. This works when not having an anchor tag infront.

CSS:

```
#china:hover ~ #map {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="map-container">
    <a href="#article-info-china"><article id="china"></article></a>
    <article id="map"></article>
</section>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I'd say the issue here is not the tilde, but the fact that the element with id `china`  inside the anchor (`<a>`) element is _not_ a sibling of the element with id `map`. So the css rule simply does not select that element.

Comment: They don't share the same parent in your markup so this will not work. Can you put the ID on the link instead?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes #China is an image that should link to another article. Not sure how I should go about changing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior. The `~` selector won't do the trick because it tries to find `#map` element right after `#china` which is not the case. In order to work you have oto set the `:hover` selector to the anchor tag, like this: `a:hover ~ #map`.

This will select the `#map` element because it is right after the ancor tag.

But you may not want to have the opacity when outside `#china` element.

Comment: Thanks. It's usually the simple things that breaks my code.

Answer (score 1):

`a[href$='#article-info-china']` is used to select `<a>` with `href = #article-info-china`

```css
a[href$='#article-info-china']:hover ~ #map {
opacity: 0.1;
}

#map{
  
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="map-container">
    <a href="#article-info-china"><article id="china">hello</article></a>
    <article id="map"></article>
</section>
```

Comment: China is an image, else I would just have the anchor tag inside

Comment: if you want to do this using `china`, it'll be better to use javascript

Comment: Sorry, should have pointed out this is for my 1st year project in web. We're not allowed to use JS. Thanks though :)